# Dyanmic url in laravel

Tags: php, url, dynamic, laravel, url-routing

I am a beginner in laravel so please excuse me if this is a simple question

I am trying to pass a db variable through my url so e.g blog?=category
It displays all results but when i change the url to blog/category1 it doesn't display anything.

DB Fields:id,category, name
          1  category1 test

This is in my routes:

```
Route::get( '/blog', 'BlogController@index' );
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
 Route::get('blog/{category}', function($category = null)
{
// get all the blog stuff from database
// if a category was passed, use that
// if no category, get all posts
if ($category)
$posts = Post::where('category', '=', $category);
else
$posts = Post::all();

// show the view with blog posts (app/views/blog.blade.php)
return View::make('blog.index')
->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

BlogController

```
class BlogController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        // get the posts from the database by asking the Active Record for "all"
        $posts = Post::all();

        // and create a view which we return - note dot syntax to go into folder
        return View::make('blog.index', array('posts' => $posts));
    }
}
```

This is my view layout:

```
@extends('base')

@section('content')
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<h2>{{ $post->id }}</h2>
<p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
@endforeach
@stop
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `->get()` after your Eloquent query to fetch the results.

```
Route::get('blog/{category}', function($category = null)
{
    // get all the blog stuff from database
    // if a category was passed, use that
    // if no category, get all posts
    if ($category)
        $posts = Post::where('category', '=', $category)->get();
    else
        $posts = Post::all();

    // show the view with blog posts (app/views/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('blog.index')->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution. ;)